# How to remove empty elements from arrayList in this code

Tags: java, arrays, io

I experienced a problem with my code where I can not remove empty elements in my arrayList. It ends up returning `[1, 2, 3, 0, 8,  , 12 ,  ,   34 , 0 ]` however those empty elements do not get removed after numerous attempts

```
public static ArrayList<String> readNumbers() {
    Scanner inFile = null;
    File file = null;
    String filePath = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a file path"));
    int size = 0;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        file = new File(filePath);
        inFile = new Scanner(file);
        int skippedCounter = 0;

        for(int i = 0; inFile.hasNext(); i++){
            if(inFile.hasNextInt())
                result.add(inFile.next());
            else{
                String strOut = "";
                String data = inFile.nextLine();

                for(int j = 0; j <= data.length() - 1; j++){
                    if(!Character.isLetter(data.charAt(j))){
                        strOut += data.charAt(j);
                    }
                    else
                        skippedCounter++;
                }
                if(!strOut.isEmpty())
                    result.add(strOut);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    } 
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Not a number");
    }
    finally {
        inFile.close();
    }
    int count = 0;
    result.removeIf(String::isEmpty);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String::isEmpty()` only checks if the length of the string is zero. It doesn't return `true` if your string consists of only spaces or other whitespace.

You can do a `String.trim()` first and then check for `String.isEmpty()`.

```
result.removeIf(s -> s.trim().isEmpty());
```

Comment: Hi this fixed it and I appreciate it, what does the -> mean?

Comment: It's a lambda. It's short for `new Function<String,String>()  { public String apply(String s) { return s.trim().isEmpty(); } }`, basically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Java 8 and up, you can do something like this to remove all empty values from list:
`results.removeIf(item -> != StringUtils.isEmpty(item));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
List<Integer> listWithNulls = Arrays.asList(1,null, 2, 3, null, 4);

List<Integer> listWithoutNulls = listWithNulls.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```